# Out of Band Access - what's your favorite Terminal / Console Server

Tags: console, colocation, datacenter

I am looking for a 32 or 48 port Console Server for access to routers, switches console ports in our Colo - any recommendations?

The devices it would connect to are mainstream (Cisco, HP, NetApp, etc).

Be nice if it supported RADIUS, encryption, etc.

I like this one from Black Box

http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Detail.aspx/Value-Line-48-Port-Console-Server/LES1148A

But ValueLine makes you buy a dongle for each connection type ($15-20) which can get pricey.

http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Detail.aspx/Cicso-Compatible-Console-Port-Adapter-for-Value-Line-Console-Servers/LES1116A%C4%82CISCO

But this may be required for any Console Server.

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: You can find rollover cable adapters for much cheaper than that.  Shop around, or consider making your own rollover cables (at custom lengths, too!

Answer (score 1):

We've looked at [Raritan devices](http://www.raritan.com/products/serial-console-management/) for this.

We use Raritan KVM switches and they've always worked well for us.  We don't have enough serial devices in one location that we need a serial switch, so we've only ever demo'd a Dominion SX as a test, but it was pretty simple to get it up and running.  Raritan's KSX II does both KVM and serial switch in one unit.

Answer (score 0):

[Jeremy Stretch](http://packetlife.net/users/stretch/) has been using an [Opengear CM4116 console server](http://www.opengear.com/product-cm4000-feature.html) for his [Packetlife Community Lab](http://packetlife.net/wiki/packet-life-community-lab/) for some time now.

[The lab faq](http://packetlife.net/wiki/community-lab-faq/) gives some informations about the console server (forbidden commands, send a break), and [this link](http://packetlife.net/wiki/how-community-lab-works/) explain how the console server is linked to the lab server, which handles AAA (radius server).

Opengear also gives [the source code](http://www.opengear.com/sourcecode.html) of their products, if you want to customize your console server.

For my personal needs, I went the cheap way and built my own with a computer, three pci cards w/ 4 serial ports on each, and [conserver](http://www.conserver.com/). This works well and is easily expandable.